# How import mysql file to phpmyadmin with terminal

Tags: 14.04, mysql, connection

I am trying to import sql file to phpmyadmin, i am't able to connect to mysql in terminal by using below command.

```
cd /opt/lampp/mysql
```

Comment: how would a change directory allow you to connect to mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Default command line method to import an exported SQL file:

```
mysql -u {user} -p {database_to_import_into} < /dir/to/file.sql
```

The database needs to exists before you do this.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am using (Xampp for ubuntu : https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) i t's not working

Comment: So? mysql is mysql; I would advice to dump xampp and use our own lampserver. ALL information you find on Ubuntu will be targetted to our own stack.